# jQuery Cycle Plugin Multiples Values for 'next' and 'prev'

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-cycle

I want to make it so div's with the class `.image` and links with the id `#next` advance the slideshow with the [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). I tried the code below but only the `#next` is working, not both values. Is there a way to have two values for the the `next` and `prev` values with this plugin? Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#slideshow').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            timeout: 0,
            next: '.image' && '#next',
            prev: '#prev',
            speed: 500
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it our myself! This is the syntax for others that are curious:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#slideshow').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            timeout: 0,
            next: '.image, #next',
            prev: '#prev',
            speed: 500
        });
    });
```